# CSS to make an input width responsive when next to fixed width items without using flexbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I use CSS to make an input flexible while next to 2 fixed width buttons?

I have 2 buttons which are fixed width, next to an input on the same row which I need to be flexible and always consume the rest of the space available in that row.

Needs to be supported by most browsers back to IE10 era.

I have attached a screenshot below to illustrate what I mean.

[image: flexible buttons issue displayed]

You can view the site here: http://helenshill.com.au/beta3/shop/

HTML markup:

```
<form class="cart-num" action="index.html" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number quantity" id="quantity-box" value="1" min="1" max="100">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button id="minus-btn-small" type="button" class="quantity-left-minus quantity-increment btn btn-number" data-type="minus" data-field="">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
      </button>
  </span>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button id="plus-btn-small" type="button" class="quantity-right-plus quantity-increment btn btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      </button>
  </span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below works by using `display:table` instead of flexbox, this will adjust to the size of the contents, so by making the 2 buttons a fixed width, the rest of the space will be allocated to the input and will change wit hthe screen size.

Working Snippet:

```css
  section {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  padding: 1em 0 0;
}

div.col {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
}

.col.button {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #EEEEEE;
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col button">+</div>
  <div class="col button">-</div>

</section>
```

**Snippet with your HTML**
Note that you need to add a container element around your textbox, but thats the only change required for the HTML.
Also, the + and - don't show here because I don't have whatever library you are using.

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

span.col {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
}

.input-group-btn {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}

button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  background: #FFF;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

button:hover {
  background: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<form class="cart-num" action="index.html" method="post">
  <span class="col"> 
  <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number quantity" id="quantity-box" value="1" min="1" max="100">
  </span>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button id="minus-btn-small" type="button" class="quantity-left-minus quantity-increment btn btn-number" data-type="minus" data-field="">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
  </span><span class="input-group-btn">
      <button id="plus-btn-small" type="button" class="quantity-right-plus quantity-increment btn btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  </button>
  </span>
</form>
```